# MySQL threads created quickly growing

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

We run a PHP application using PDO. We keep losing connections to the database when we run short scripts and we do not use persistent connections. Upon querying the connections we see the below data. The `Threads_created` and `Connections` are increasing by 100-200 per second and we cannot figure out why. We assume this is why we are running into connection issues. We have checked the `processlist` and there is really nothing running. Is there a way to figure out exactly where in the application these connections are being created? We cannot find a way to figure it out since its a large application and we have run out of ideas. Thanks in advance for some insight.

[image]

Comment: I bet you're creating a connection in a loop.

Comment: Thats my thought, but I would need to know where since its a large app.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

Comment: This can happen if you are not explicitly closing the connections you "lose" when you are done with them; you end up creating new ones faster than the "dead" ones are terminated by the server. I temporarily "created" a similar problem in a VBA application I was handed years ago; once I sped up the short and simple function calls, reducing load time from 2-5 minutes to <1 minute, the load would fail as it exhausted the connections....that was when I started moving the "application" to using a persistent shared connection for most methods.

Comment: Are you using a persistent connection?

Comment: Are you still struggling with Threads_created?  Give us some form of news, please.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically, you can 
SET GLOBAL thread_cache_size = 100    #  CAP suggested per MySQL v 8
and they will not grow paired with connections.  Plus you will save a ton of CPU.

If this works for you, add to your my.cfg / .ini for next restart.

Comment: @naterade Have you made any progress?  Please let us know your status on growth of threads_created management.

Answer (score 0):

In your my.cfg/ini  [mysqld] section, ensure you have

```
thread_cache_size=100  # to support 100,000+ connections
```

threads_created will drop dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue:  If you're using jQuery to bind a script load to a button click (for example) you could be binding it multiple times, in which case the button click will execute multiple times.  And if that function creates a single MySQL thread, then you could be inadvertently creating many MySQL threads in an instant.

If you have this...

```
$('.additemsbutton').click(function(){
    functionThatCreatesDBConnection();
});
```

or this...

```
$('.additemsbutton').on('click',function(){
    functionThatCreatesDBConnection();
});
```

you should change it to this...

```
$('.additemsbutton').off('click').on('click',function(){
    functionThatCreatesDBConnection();
});
```

This last example first removes any previous bindings, before adding this binding.  That way you only ever have one binding, and the function is only ever called once.

Comment: Is this a way to figure out exactly where in the application these connections are being created? Because that was what the OP was concerned about - apart from configuring the MySQL server itself I guess.

Comment: There is no super easy way to do this, but this is what you can do:  Keep your developer tools open to the Network tab, enter .php into your filter (assuming you're running php) so that you only see php files being loaded, and then go through your app and start opening pages, inserting data, updating data, etc.  As you execute these actions, your network tab will show you which php scripts are being loaded, and assuming that each script opens a new DB connection, you can see how many connections (threads) are being created by that action.  Then see if you can optimize your code.

Comment: @Vicent: Sorry, this should be more visible: I was not asking for technical reasons, but to find out if the answer answers the question or might be answering a different question and was just placed here. Perhaps there is a better candidate with more Javascript context?

Comment: @hakre This answer does answer the question, since the OP is looking to track down the cause of the many DB connections, and JavaScript can be used to load PHP scripts which create DB connections.  A single PHP file alone likely only creates a single DB thread/connection, but loading that same PHP file many times (inadvertently) creates many DB threads, and this can easily happen in the scenario I describe.  A scenario like this would not be super obvious, but it could be causing a lot of database connections, so I thought it worthwhile to post here.

Comment: Yes for that part I'm with you, and thinking: How can we say that the MySQL query in the PHP code is triggered by Javascript events in the browser in a fan-in fashion? That's the part I'm concerned about. So if there would be a question with this more specific scenario, I'd say your answer would be on point. It's not that want to say your answer is wrong in that regard, but more the question if it as the right place to be found. E.g. perhaps with a similar question that specifically tags [tag:javascript] as well.

Comment: @hakre in my experience, people looking to figure out their DB threads issue, never even think to look at their JavaScript, because it's counter intuitive, so I doubt anybody tags their question with JavaScript.  I think the answer belongs here, but if you think it's unclear, feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: Yes, this is fine to remind on for let's say a forum discussion or similar, but for Q&A this would mean that the question is being corrected or closed if that turned out to be the answer. I merely commented on your answer as it came late to this question and then IMHO its useful to search if there is a better place as there are many questions around the topic, so probably you can find a sweeter spot. That's all (and that would be the edit I suggest, but I'm confident you can do this search better and I'm not a moderator so can't move it in the end if I would found a candidate).